# How could I clean TextView after logout?

Tags: java, android

I have an issue with my android app. The user info in the TextView of my DrawerLayout will not updated but remain those of the last registration. How can I delete them after logging out? I try with this but it doesn't work:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private ImageView imageProfile;
    private TextView mUsername;
    private TextView mEmail;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 1000;

    //Firebase stuff
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private FirebaseFirestore mStore;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        setupUIMenu();

        String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_email");

        mUsername.setText("");
        mEmail.setText("");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        imageProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent openGalleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(openGalleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
            }
        });


        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference databaseUsers = database.child("users");

        Query usersQuery = databaseUsers.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
        usersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                try {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    mUsername.setText(user.getUserName());
                    mEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });

if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new MenuFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_menu);
        }

private void setupUIMenu() {
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View navHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        imageProfile = navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);
        mUsername = navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.userName_nav);
        mEmail = navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.userEmail_nav);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_menu:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new MenuFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new SendFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new SettingsFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                logout(item);
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void logout(MenuItem item) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I added my whole MenuActivity.java but username and email still remain void. I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: How do you set text for that TextView? You could setText("") before logging out but maybe it is better if you just write over it each time. So that's why I ask, how do you set that text? How is it possible that your drawerlayout info is visible before the user logs in? You can even try on starting an activity where your DrawerLayout is to setText("") as soon as the activity starts.

Comment: @SlothCoding I edited my question and I wrote how I set text in TextView

Comment: Well in your onDataChange you retrieve users from the database and go through each one of them that you have created in your database. This way the user that is last in your DataSnapshot snapshot will set values to mUsername and mEmail. Maybe create a model User and use it to store your current user from Firebase. That way you'll always have the User info in your code to take and change every time someone else logs in.

Comment: I've model User and I've tried with this:  for(DataSnapshot datasnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                        User user = datasnap.getValue(User.class);
                        mUsername.setText(user.getUserName());
                        mEmail.setText(user.getEmail());  but it doesn't work. I don't know if it is wrong

Comment: Is your User.class the same as the data you have in your Firebase database? Also, this doesn't solve your problem either. Since you have an array of users and you just get each user and setText() for every textView. So you take the first one and set text with that user data, then you take the second one and set text with that user data, and so on. This way, the data will always be from the last user in the list which is probably the first user you ever created in that database.

Comment: You need some kind of check if datasnap,child("userName").getValue().toString() is equal to your current user. It could be a child("email") or anything else. If you are using email to log in or register just find the user by that email and get his data from the snapshot.

Comment: Yes, the data are always of the last registered user. For registration I use username and email, but I don't know how to check if the user is the current one. Could you tell me something more about it, even with an example if you can?

Comment: Check firebase documentation on how to use .orderBy("email@domain.com") for example. That way you can get back value from users with the user who has "email@domain.com" as his email as the first user in your snapshot. In that case, just take the first child, and set values with his data, don't loop through the object. An even better solution would be if Firebase has .equals(email), which will give back only one value. For this maybe check to addSingleValueEventListener() or something like that. I am in a hurry so if you don't fix it just tag me again I'll help later.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try with these solutions and if I can't, I'll write here again.

Comment: @SlothCoding I've tried to add some check but with this kind of solution, in debug mode it skips to end

Comment: But what happened with your data? This Listener is asynchronous. To check what happens in there put a breakpoint inside where you take values from a snapshot and wait and see what happens in there.

Comment: I don't know what happens to my data because adding the breakpoint completely skips the instruction. It seems that they are null

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that each user is saved with a random key.

Comment: What data do you have under user in the database?

Comment: I added my database structure in the question

Comment: The user data are null, but I don't know why. I tried to print this:      String current = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(); and it's null

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's do it step by step. First on your `LoginActivity` where your user logins and enters email use `.putExtra()` on `Intent` to provide that email to your `MainActivity` that starts after. Do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("user_email", email.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then to get this value in `MainActivity` copy this in `onCreate`:

```
String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_email");
```

After that call this to retrieve user from Firebase database:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference databaseUsers = database.child("users");

Query usersQuery = databaseUsers.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
usersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       try {
            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

            mUsername.setText(user.getName());
            mEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

This will set text to your `DrawerLayout` username and email `TextView`.

And your `User.java` looks like this:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String uid;
    private String userName;

    public User () {
             //Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public String getName() { return userName };
    public String email() { return email };
}
```

This should work now. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I tried this solution but this way nothing is entered, even when a user signs up. I am really desperate

Comment: How many users do you have in your database?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is caused by the child having the key generated randomly with the push().

Comment: Now, I've only two users

Comment: Nah, that shouldn't be a problem. Can you try my code and put a breakpoint inside onDataChanged when doing a query. And see if the user is null? And can you please share your whole MainActivity class?

Comment: I've added a breakpoint inside onDataChanged and the user is null. Now I add my whole MenuActivity class with your changes

Comment: Did you create your User class as I wrote above? This is working for me, I don't know why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Now, it's working but without setting textview (mUsername.setText(""); ). Thank you very much. If I may ask you, is it necessary to send the email via intent between activities? Or is there another way?

Comment: I think it is necessary because you need something to filter your data from the database. If you don't have mail then you won't be able to filter that data. This way you get back ONLY ONE user that has that unique email address in his data. I'll delete "mUsername.setText(""); from my answer. If it helped accept it for people to know that this is a solution. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and for the reply. Yes, I think it's not necessary, since it worked with me even without setText (""). Thanks again for everything.

Comment: No problem mate, I am glad I could help.